# Solving non linear ODE $y''(x)+x^2y'(x)+y(x)^3=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solving non linear ODE $y''(x)+x^2y'(x)+y(x)^3=0$ with $y(0)=y'(0)=0$ and $y(x):[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$

There's a hint to multiply by $y'(x)$ and then integrate from $0$ to $x_0$

I tried multiplying by $y'(x)$ and integrating to get $\int_{0}^{x_0} y'(x)y''(x)dx+\int_{0}^{x_0} x^2y'(x)^2+\int_{0}^{x_0} y'(x)y(x)^3=0$

To get $\frac{1}{2} y'(x_0)^2+\int_{0}^{x_0} x^2y'(x)^2+\frac{1}{4}y(x_0)^4=0$

But I cant see what to do with the middle integral.

Comment: Are the dependent and independent variable both taken to be real-valued? Also, is the last equation what you got, or are there exponents missing?

Comment: @K.B Dave Yes, I missed the exponents. And also yes it was for $y(x):[0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$

Comment: It's a trap! But seriously, you can directly see what one solution to the IVP is (not the general solution of course), you only have to show that it is unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac12 y′(x)^2+∫_0^x x_1^2y′(x_1)^2+\frac14 y(x)^4\geq 0$
with equality iff $\frac12 y′(x)^2=∫_0^x x_1^2y′(x_1)^2=\frac14 y(x)^4=0$

so y must be the zero function.

Comment: Easier, direct insertion of $y=0$ into the DE shows that it is a solution for the IVP. The equation is polynomial, thus smooth, thus locally Lipschitz, which implies uniqueness, there is no other solution for this IVP.

Comment: are you referring to Picard-Lindelof Theorem? i think the diff eqn has to be in the form y'(x)=f(y,x) first.

Comment: Transforming a higher-order DE into a first-order system is standard. And yes, the uniqueness claim of P-L is used.